# How make component finish loading first before html in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have this dashboard page with charts and some cards with data. The function to retrieve the data is in ngOnInit() but the problem is that when the page is loaded, the data shows 0. If i click on the chart or  something, then the data loads in. Is there anyway to make it straightaway fetch  data upon page load? I tried setting a boolean where it will turn true at the end of nginit but it still doesnt work.

```
<div *ngIf="isLoaded">
Page here
</div>
```

This is the ts file.

```
export class DashboardAgentComponent implements OnInit {

totalAssigned=0;
totalAssignedHigh=0;
totalAssignedMed=0;
totalAssignedLow=0;
totalPending=0;
totalPendingHigh=0;
totalPendingMed=0;
totalPendingLow=0;
totalUnassigned=0;
public allTags$ = new BehaviorSubject<Tag[]>([]);
public threeDaysPending = 0;
public sevenDaysPending =0;
public fourteenDaysPending = 0;

public threeDaysAssigned = 0;
public sevenDaysAssigned =0;
public fourteenDaysAssigned = 0;
public isLoaded : boolean =  false;


ngOnInit() :void{
this.getTotalAssigned();

}

public trackByFn = (i: number, tag: Tag) => tag.id;



getTotalAssigned()
{
  this.mailboxTags.getTotalPending().subscribe((tags: Tag[]) => {
    console.log(tags);
    // this.allTags$.next(tags);
    for (let index = 0; index < tags.length; index++) {
      if(tags[index].name == 'pending' && tags[index].type=='view')
      {
        this.totalPending = tags[index].tickets_count;
      }

      else if(tags[index].name == 'unassigned')
      {
        this.totalUnassigned = tags[index].tickets_count;
      }

      else if(tags[index].name == 'assigned'&& tags[index].type=='view')
      {
        this.totalAssigned = tags[index].tickets_count;
      }
    }
 });
this.getPendingTickets();

}

getPendingTickets()
{
this.mailboxTags.getPendingHighTickets().subscribe((res: any) => {
  let currentDate: any = new Date();
  
    for (let index = 0; index < res.pagination.data.length; index++) {
      if(res.pagination.data[index].status=="pending")
      {
        let createdDate: any = new Date(res.pagination.data[index].created_at);
        var diffDays:any = Math.floor((currentDate - createdDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        if(diffDays>3 && diffDays<7)
        {
          this.threeDaysPending++;
        }

        else if(diffDays>=7 && diffDays<14)
        {
          this.sevenDaysPending++;
        }

        else if(diffDays>=14)
        {
          this.fourteenDaysPending++;
        }
      }
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < res.pagination.data.length; index++) {
      if(res.pagination.data[index].status=="assigned")
      {
        let createdDate: any = new Date(res.pagination.data[index].created_at);
        var diffDays:any = Math.floor((currentDate - createdDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        if(diffDays>3 && diffDays<7)
        {
          this.threeDaysAssigned++;
        }

        else if(diffDays>=7 && diffDays<14)
        {
          this.sevenDaysAssigned++;
        }

        else if(diffDays>=14)
        {
          this.fourteenDaysAssigned++;
        }
      }
    }
   
    this.isLoaded =  true;
    
    
  
  
 });
 }


constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, public mailboxTags: MailboxTagsService) {}

}
```

Basically all the data that will be used is in the ngOnInit functions.

This is the html. It's not complete but the others are similar.

```
<div class="grid-container"  *ngIf="isLoaded   == true">
<h1 class="mat-h1">Dashboard</h1>
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="550px" colWidth="100px">
  <mat-grid-tile   class="grid-tile"  [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
    <ng-container >
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card" >
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            Unassigned
            <button mat-icon-button class="more-button" 
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Toggle menu">
              <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
              <button mat-menu-item>Expand</button>
              <button mat-menu-item>Remove</button>
            </mat-menu>
          </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
          <div>{{totalUnassigned}}</div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
    </ng-container>
   </mat-grid-tile>
   </mat-grid-list>
   </div>
```

So the totalUnassigned is 0 unless i open my matmenu then the data gets updated.

Comment: If the data is loaded asynchronous then you need to wait for the call to complete before setting isLoaded to true. You could also look into Angular Resolvers, which make sure data is loaded for ngOnInit is called.

Comment: @andyiscoding check my updated answer

Comment: Route resolver is a perfect feature for this situation.
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: @surajrawat thanks, i'll take a look

Comment: @Nathan Thanks to you too for suggesting Angular Resolvers

Answer (score 1):

> I tried setting a boolean where it will turn true at the end of nginit
> but it still doesnt work.

You must not set the `isLoaded=true` at the end of `ngOnInit()`. This does not ensure that all data have been successfully loaded.

I am pretty sure you miss the basics of asynchronous programming where you must make any changes inside the callback function that get's called.

```
ngOnInit() {
   ...
   ..asynchronousCall...
   ...

  this.isLoaded=true
}
```

Above scenario won't work.

```
  ngOnInit() {
       ...
       ..asynchronousCall.subscribe( e => {
          this.isLoaded=true
        });
       ...
    }
```

Above scenario will work because the boolean will be updated when the asyncrhonous call back function get's executed and data has been successfully fetched from the backend

**Edit:**
After you posted all the code my first estimation for your error was correct.

You can solve this by
moving the method invocation `this.getPendingTickets();` inside the subscription of `getTotalAssigned()`. This way the pending tickets would be fetched only when the totalAsigned tickets have been fetched.

Also move the `this.isLoaded =  true;` inside the subscription of `getPendingTickets()`

After you refactor your code like this you will achieve that `this.isLoaded` turns true only when TotalAsigned has been fetched and pendingTickets have been fetched.

Comment: Even better would be to combine the 2 observables somehow with `forkJoin` for instance and change `isLoaded` once the combined result is available.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i did like you said which is putting the getting pending tickets and setting isloaded inside the get totalassigned but the html is still showing the initial values before data is fetched which is 0.

Comment: @andyiscoding then the relevant html must be outside `<div *ngIf="isLoaded">` Correct it and it will work

Comment: All the html is inside the div ngIf already.  The  only  thing  outside  is  the material navbar  which is irrelevant. i tested it, if i didnt set isLoaded = true, the page is  blank. If i set it, the page loads but with initial values 0.

Comment: @andyiscoding update the question with your current code to see where the error is

Comment: @andyiscoding you still make `this.isLoaded = true` in the end of ngOnInit. Read my answer carefully and update your code accordingly

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos My apology, i didnt update the original ts code in the ques. It's now updated like i said. I did follow your suggestions and it's still not working.

Comment: @andyiscoding `this.isLoaded =  true;` must go inside the subscription of `this.getPendingTickets();` not where you have it now

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos Can  you check the updated if  that's what you mean. If that is, the  page is blank now until i click on the material navbar

Comment: yes because only after the data is loaded you allow the screen to show now

Comment: Yeah but the problem still remains as before. The data wont load automatically, it needs some clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using  Angular Resolvers. The ngIf method alone wasnt working for some reason. Here's my updated code:

```
  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, public mailboxTags: MailboxTagsService, private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
 this.respond = this._route.snapshot.data['tickets'];
 this.tag =this._route.snapshot.data['tag'];
 this.userID = this._route.snapshot.data['id'];

let currentDate: any = new Date();
  
    for (let index = 0; index < this.respond.pagination.data.length; index++) {
      if(this.respond.pagination.data[index].assigned_to == this.userID)
      {
        if(this.respond.pagination.data[index].status=="pending")
      {
        let createdDate: any = new Date(this.respond.pagination.data[index].created_at);
        var diffDays:any = Math.floor((currentDate - createdDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        if(diffDays>3 && diffDays<7)
        {
          this.threeDaysPending++;
        }

        else if(diffDays>=7 && diffDays<14)
        {
          this.sevenDaysPending++;
        }

        else if(diffDays>=14)
        {
          this.fourteenDaysPending++;
        }
      }
      }
      
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < this.respond.pagination.data.length; index++) {
      if(this.respond.pagination.data[index].assigned_to == this.userID){
        if(this.respond.pagination.data[index].status=="assigned")
      {
        let createdDate: any = new Date(this.respond.pagination.data[index].created_at);
        var diffDays:any = Math.floor((currentDate - createdDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        if(diffDays>3 && diffDays<7)
        {
          this.threeDaysAssigned++;
        }

        else if(diffDays>=7 && diffDays<14)
        {
          this.sevenDaysAssigned++;
        }

        else if(diffDays>=14)
        {
          this.fourteenDaysAssigned++;
        }
      }
      }
    }  

    for (let index = 0; index < this.tag.length; index++) {
      if(this.tag[index].name == 'pending' && this.tag[index].type=='view')
      {
        this.totalPending = this.tag[index].tickets_count;
      }

      else if(this.tag[index].name == 'unassigned')
      {
        this.totalUnassigned = this.tag[index].tickets_count;
      }

      else if(this.tag[index].name == 'assigned'&& this.tag[index].type=='view')
      {
        this.totalAssigned = this.tag[index].tickets_count;
      }
    }
    this.isLoaded=true;
   }
```

Comment: you didn't need resolvers. Your problem is you still had `this.getPendingTickets();` outside subscription. It was `}); this.getPendingTickets(); ..` when it should be `this.getPendingTickets(); });` Subscribe should close `})` after the call `this.getPendingTickets()`